# Semantic Zoom on hub control with button as header on Windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a Button with content as header of my hub sections within a hub control. Now I want to enable semantic zoom for this control. So I've downloaded the sample from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-Hub-control-sample-5d116fa9. But because I'm using a Button as Header I can't apply the code from the sample.

So how can I use a button as header and use semantic zoom?

Answer (score 1):

No, of course you can.

```
<SemanticZoom>
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <Hub>
            <Hub.Header>
                <Button>
                    Hello World
                </Button>
            </Hub.Header>
        </Hub>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <GridView />
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
</SemanticZoom>
```

The header template does not make a difference.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yes. It is working. But if I'm clicking on an item in the zoomoutview the hub section won't go at the selected item. So how can I do this?

Comment: MSDN explains this `if (e.IsSourceZoomedInView == false) { e.DestinationItem.Item = e.SourceItem.Item; }` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.semanticzoom.aspx